# jQuery to Send Email from Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have my form send me an email every time the "Submit Query" button is clicked. The form is validated and brings the user to a confirmation page after the button is clicked, but I get no email.

Form code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sumbit').click(function() {
        $('#contactform').attr('action',
                       'mailto:chinochinako@gmail.com?subject=Jeannette Chambliss Digital Portfolio' +
                       $('#name').val() + '&body=' + $('#email').val() + '&body=' + $('#comments').val() + '&body=');
        $('#contactform').submit();
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form onSubmit="MM_validateForm('name','','R','comments','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" id="contactform">
 <label for="name">Full Name:
  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" required="required"></label><br /><br />
 <label for="email">Email:
 <input name="email" type="email" id="email" required="required"></label><br /><br />
 <label for="comments">Comments:
 <textarea name="comments" id="comments" required></textarea></label><br /><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" formaction="confirmation.html" formmethod="POST" formtarget="_self" action="mailto:chinochinako@gmail.com">
</form>

<script src="js/form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Forms can't send emails.

Comment: You can't send emails with JS alone, you need a server side script that you call with your ajax.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to do--have the form open an email so that the user can submit it to me as they wish. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
var contact = $("#contact").val();
$("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.
// Checking for blank fields.
if (name == '' || email == '' || contact == '') {
alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
} else {
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("contact_form.php", {
name1: name,
email1: email,
message1: message,
contact1: contact
}, function(data) {
$("#returnmessage").append(data); // Append returned message to message paragraph.
if (data == "Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon.") {
$("#form")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
}
});
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#contactform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr(
      'action',
      'mailto:rafaeljunqueira.rs@gmail.com?subject=Jeannette Chambliss Digital Portfolio');
    console.log($(this)[0].action);
    return true;
  });
});
```

```css
form ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

form ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="contactform">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Comments" id="comments" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stack Overlfow.

I suspect you are missing the `.preventDefault()` to prevent the click event from proceeding.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    $('#contactform').attr(
      'action',
      'mailto:chinochinako@gmail.com?subject=Jeannette Chambliss Digital Portfolio');
    $('#contactform').submit();
  });
});
```

Mind you, if the user bypasses clicking the button, and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this code will not execute. You may want to consider moving your verification code into the `submit` event in jQuery, and move this code in there too.

I noticed a potential typo: `$('#sumbit').click(function() {`

Did you mean: `$('#submit').click(function() {`

**Update**

*According to the HTML specifications, the action field of the form should be a correctly formed HTTP URL. So ‘mailto:’ is not valid for the action field.*

Also, this will not "send" the email. It will only ask the default email program to compose a message that the user can send. If you want the data submitted to be sent via SMTP, this must be done by a server-side script (ASP/ASP.NET, PHP, ColdFusion, Perl, Python...) via a form handler.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#contactform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr(
      'action',
      'mailto:chinochinako@gmail.com?subject=Jeannette Chambliss Digital Portfolio');
    console.log($(this)[0].action);
    return true;
  });
});
```

```css
form ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

form ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="contactform">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Comments" id="comments" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, however this still is not working for me. I updated the JS script, but still no email. Also, the user has no way to submit the form outside of hitting the button, so using "Enter" to bypass the button is not a concern.

Comment: @ChinoChinako will see if I can prepare an example. Baring in mind what was commented, the form itself, cannot send the email. when you use `mailto:user@domain.com` as the action, this asks the browser to then ask your default email program to compose a message. It's not always perfect and there are a LOT of factors that can make it fail.

Comment: Thank you, @Twisty! This still isn't working for me, but perhaps I am still doing something incorrectly. I'll keep playing with the code and hope that I can figure it out. I appreciate you taking the time to look into this (and find my spelling error).

Comment: What browser are you using for testing?

Comment: Firefox. It seems to be the most responsive with my code.

Comment: @ChinoChinako based on my reading, this `action` will only work with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm trying to recode it all using PHP now. I need to figure out my server email address, but otherwise I may have found a work-around to this issue I'm having with jQuery. Thank you for all of your help!